# How can I have an encrypted input in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program that requires a user to input their gmail usernames and passwords. When the user types in their password, I want the characters to be displayed as asterisks. Is this possible for a command-line program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getpass.getpass()`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) doesn't show asterisks but instead suppresses all output, which is expected behavior on some systems.

Comment: Thank you. That isn't what I was looking for, but it works just as well.